# Can't mysqldump anymore after upgrading to Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel, command

today I decided to upgrade my laravel project to version 7.0. From that point on I can't mysqldump my database thru artisan command. Any suggest?

```
php artisan backup:run

   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException 

  The command "'mysqldump --user=***** --password=****** ****** > /home2/****/subdomains/intranet/storage/app/backups/backup-2020-03-12_15:15:18.sql'" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)
```

Code working in Laravel 6:

```
class BackupRun extends Command
{
 protected $signature = 'backup:run';
 protected $description = 'Run Backup';

 protected $process;
 protected $filename;


 public function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct();

     $this->filename = 'backup-' . strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') . '.sql';

     $this->process = new Process([sprintf(
         'mysqldump --user=%s --password=%s %s > %s',
         config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
         config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
         config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
         storage_path("app/backups/{$this->filename}")
     )]);
 }

 public function handle()
 {
     $this->process->mustRun();
 }
}
```

Comment: Does `mysqldump` exist? Does it work if you try and run it from a terminal

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Is this any help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/spatie-backup-and-mysqldump

Comment: I also noticed that Symphony Process now accepts an array as first argument and no more a string. I don't know if I did the right thing wrapping the sprintf command inside square brackets.

Comment: @RiggsFolly in that laracast page the use can't run the cronjob. I cannot run the artisan command.

Comment: well i will get out of the way and let all the others get a chance

Comment: If i exec the command thru the php exec function I get "Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure."

Comment: Well I would say that proves that mysqldump actually exists :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did something like this "(mysqldump %s --user=%s --password=%s > %s) 2>&1" avoiding warnings. This works. Using the Symphony Process Class it doesn't. That's weird. Well, the important thing is that it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I also had this same problem, and found a solution, with laravel 7 you cannot use the symbol ">", use the parameter --result-file =

```
    $this->process = new Process([
        'mysqldump',
        '--user=' . config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
        '--password=' . config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
        '--result-file=' . $file
    ]);
```

Comment: It helped me too!

Answer (score 2):

I solved using the *exec()* php function instead of the *Symphony Process Class*. Too bad.

Also, using 2>&1 avoids warnings like "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure".

You can substitute the config data with your ENV variables.

Cheers!

```
class BackupRun extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'backup:run';
    protected $description = 'Run Backup';

    protected $filename;
    protected $process;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->filename = 'backup-' . now() . '.sql';

        $this->process = sprintf(
            '(mysqldump %s --user=%s --password=%s > %s) 2>&1',
            config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
            config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
            config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
            storage_path("app/backups/{$this->filename}")
        );
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        exec($this->process);
    }
}
```